# If $\alpha $ is a root of equation $4x^2+2x-1=0$ and $f(x) =4x^3 -3x+1$ then $2[f(\alpha)+1]= $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Since $\alpha$ is a root of equation therefore $4x^2 +2x-1 =0 $ can be written as $4\alpha^2 +2\alpha -1 =0$

and $f(\alpha ) = 4\alpha^3 -3\alpha +1 = \alpha ( 4\alpha^2) -3\alpha +1 = 0 $
$\Rightarrow \alpha ( 1-2\alpha ) -3\alpha +1 =0 $

$\Rightarrow \alpha -2\alpha^2 -3\alpha +1 = 0 $

$\Rightarrow  -2\alpha^2 -2\alpha +1 = 0$

But answer is 1 , can you please help on this.

Comment: You're supposed to be calculating $2(f(\alpha)+1)$.  Keep going, I think you're fine.

Comment: Don 't set $f(\alpha)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$f(x){=4x^3-3x+1=4x^3+2x^2-x+x-2x^2-x-2x+0.5+0.5\\=x(4x^2+2x-1)-{1\over 2}(4x^2+2x-1)-x+0.5}$$

Comment: $ 2\{f(\alpha) +1\} = 2\{-\alpha + \frac{1}{2}+1\}  $, how this is equal to 1( as per the answer)

Answer (score 0):

Using Euclidean division of polynomials, we find
$$
2 (f(x)+ 1)= (2 x - 1)(4 x^2 + 2 x - 1)+(3 - 2 x)
$$

Comment: answer is given 1 how ? can you please elaborate a little , thanks

Comment: @sultan, I don't think the answer is $1$. [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4x%5E2%2B2x-1%3D0%2C+y+%3D2%28%284x%5E3+-3x%2B1%29%2B1%29) agrees.